# Failed to set Firefox Preference using Selenium [Python]

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, firefox

I wanted to set preference for my Firefox profile using selenium with python. This will force any link to be opened in the current tab.

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.link.open_external",3)
fp.set_preference("browser.link.open_newwindow",3)
fp.update_preference()
browser = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
```

However, when my program starts Firefox, the preference are not updated.

Comment: What are your exact manual steps? Where do you see the error? Can you provide a sample URL? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB ,1) what i'm trying to do, i want the browser open a webpage, and click the link on the webpage. I got it work, but the link opened in a new window. i wanted the URL to be opened  in the current tab. 2) I opened `about:config` to check if the preference are updated. unfortunately not. 3) this is example url: https://plus.google.com/114766887193183719117/posts/X2kq16nAHpx

Comment: Can you provide a sample URL for my reference? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB I tried the steps given here https://www.ghacks.net/2009/07/03/force-firefox-to-open-links-in-same-tab/

Comment: Those are about the settings. What is the URL on which you are trying the steps?

Comment: @DebanjanB plus.google.com/114766887193183719117/posts/X2kq16nAHpx  this is the url. my problem here, the preferences like being ignored. i added preference to change the user agent. it working fine. but not for the browser.link